# Is File Upload through Lightning Components counted as part of Apex Heap Size?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, heap

In Winter 2018 release salesforce has released a new beta [lightning component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm) for uploading file through the **lightning:fileUpload (Beta)**.

The documentation in this link says we can upload a file of size 2 GB:

> File Upload Limits
>
> By default, you can upload up to 10 files simultaneously unless your
>   Salesforce admin has changed that limit. The org limit for the number
>   of files simultaneously uploaded is a maximum of 25 files and a
>   minimum of 3 files. The maximum file size you can upload is 2 GB. In
>   Communities, the file size limits and types allowed follow the
>   settings determined by community file moderation.

1. Apex heap size limit for synchronous transactions is 6 MB and async
   is 12 MB. If heap size is 6 OR 12 MB how can someone upload a file
   of size 2 GB?
2. When the file is transferred to server is it even considered part of
       Heap size?

Any documentation on how heap size is calculated will be really helpful.

Comment: AFAIK The fileUpload component handles things correctly, and doesn't consider Apex Heap size. Are you observing any discrepancies?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm trying to create a custom component but running in to heap size limit after 4 MB.Not sure on how Salesforce is working on a 2 GB file in the back end.